# How to roll-out bug workarounds in small organisations

Tags: updates, patch, bug

Microsoft, as of writing this question, has published a workaround for the HiveNightmare bug [CVE-2021-36934](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-36934).

The work-around consists of some commands which are to be run from privileged and non-privileged command prompts.

This is all fine and well for the individual, however, how can this be done in a small organisation with the following characteristics:

- Not all machines are geographically in the same location. This ties in with the next point
- Too big (i.e. too many users) for one person to make sure the workaround has been applied to all machines
- Too small for a central IT administration which can perform the steps remotely on all machines

How would a small business/organisation be able to tackle a bug work-around like the one mentioned?

Comment: Startup scripts that are automatically elevated as needed is typically how it's done.  [You can also remotely run PowerShell commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.1).  Running something like `Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01, Server02 -FilePath c:\Scripts\HiveNightmareFix.ps1` should accomplish your goal.  You might not be able to remotely elevate the script, so a script that schedules an automatic task, might do the [trick](https://serverfault.com/questions/473991). What have you tried?

Comment: This bug is not new (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/windows-hivenightmare-bug-could-expose-system-files-to-non-admin-users/?ftag=TREe01923b&bhid=23164040498209351948461508422926&mid=13446000&cid=712212189)   Follow this section  No patch is yet available for this flaw, prompting Microsoft and CERT to suggest the following workarounds